# Typecasting when render the prop with union Types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0, react-typescript

I have a two properties in my component.

1. prop1: CustomObject<string, type1>
2. prop2: CustomObject<string, type2> | Array
   I will accept only prop1 on priority and if prop1 is not available i will look for prop2.
   So i have created union type like the below to pass the other methods as type to make it simple.

   type inputType= type1 | type2

So in render method i am accessing the prop like this but it is accepting only any as type.

```
const propsData: any = this.props.prop1 ?? this.props.prop2
```

This statement is working but i don't want to give any

```
  const propsData: CustomObject<string | InputType> | Array<string>  = this.props.prop1 ?? this.props.prop2
```

the error i am getting in IDE is

```
Type 'String[] | CustomObject<string, type1> | CustomObject<string, type2>' is not assignable to type 'CustomObject<string, inputType> | String[]'.
```

How to handle this?

Comment: what is the `CustomType` ?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to create such an example

Comment: @dhakar It is custom object. I edited question. Its just userdefined class

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `CustomObject` expects 2 arguments, you may want to try below code as per error message.

```
const propsData: CustomObject<string, type1> | CustomObject<string, type2> | Array<string>  = this.props.prop1 ?? this.props.prop2
```

Comment: I tried this way also still get the same issue

Comment: What is error message now?